# How to find the inverse function of a logarithm?

Tags: logarithms, inverse-function

I was wondering if someone had any idea how to solve this directive?

> Find the inverse function of $$y=\frac{1}{2}(2^x - 2^{-x}).$$

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Set $t=2^x$, then rearrange to get a quadratic in $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=y=\frac{2^x-2^{-x}}{2} \implies 2^x= (y\pm\sqrt{1+y^2})$$
$$\implies x=\log_2 [y + \sqrt{1+y^2}]$$
$+$ sign has been chosen. So $$f^{-1}(x)=\log_2[x+\sqrt{1+x^2}]$$

Comment: Dr Zafar. One converts your log_2 result into a \log_e result, use the arcsinh in Bernards answer, and ..finds the result to be the same. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Rewrite $y$ as 
$$y=\frac{\mathrm e^{x\ln2}-\mathrm e^{-x\ln2}}{2}=\sinh(x\ln 2).$$